# Get Table info for Sessioned Users

Tags: php

I've made a simple login system that uses PHP to talk to mysql and start a session.
On my page accessable only to those with an active session, I'd like to display some information about the user to the user. I have a mysql config php page, a logon page, and a registration page.

I've found [a great example](https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/after-login-then-it-displays-his-personal-data-taken-from-mysql-db/4807/2), but it doesn't work in my code. I've changed some things to match my database, and session that was started by the logon page. What could I be doing wrong?

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT fname, lname FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "Hello, " . $row['fname'] . " (" . $row['lname'] . ").";
?>
```

I've even tried:

```
<?php
echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

Which doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a link to the database first, and secondly mysql is deprecated, use mysqli instead. Also take a look at prepared statements against SQL injection.

```
  <?php
     $servername = "Servername";
     $username = "Username";
     $password = "Password";
     $database = "Database";

    $link = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);
    $sql = "SELECT fname, lname FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "Hello, " . $row['name'] . " (" . $row['email'] . ").";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer! I have a small php file that the logon and registration pages use with "require_once "/path/to/file" where the SQL connection is setup. Would I link that using require_once in this instance?

Comment: Yep! Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thanks! It's 5 months coming, trust me I'll need it.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not getting results when

```
 <?php
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
 ?>
```

That means either you have not assigned a value to $_SESSION['username'] or haven't used session_start() on top of it.

try like this,

```
 <?php
    session_start(); //on top of everything
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The above one seemed to be my issue, I already started the sesh.